# How to include backend buttons css on frontend?

Tags: css, front-end, buttons

I want to include backend buttons css on frontend in a plugin?

This is how its inluded in backend:

```
http://localhost/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=1&dir=ltr&load=admin-bar,wp-admin,buttons,wp-auth-check&ver=3.6.1
```

How to include it in the frontend?

Answer (score 1):

Try enqueuing the `buttons` style:

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_wp_enqueue_scripts');
function wpse_wp_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style('buttons');
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to what you just gave. A code-only answer is not a good answer.

Comment: Shazzad is enqueuing the built in WordPress style used for buttons on the front end. It's quite straight forward to be fair. I would recommend, if needed, the user looked further into wp_enqueue_style() to get more details on it if they needed it.

Comment: @StevenJones the issue is that answers need to be self contained, and Shazzads answer doesn't actually answer the question, it's just copy pasta